# TFS Source control - Is there a way to undo a specific line in a file?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

When viewing a diff of a file in TFS, is there a way to replace a line that was changed with the line that is currently in source control?  Basically undoing only a specific line inside of a file.

For example: In TortoiseSVN, I am able to do "Revert changed lines back to the text shown in the left pane."  where text shown in left pane is text in source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot do that.

You can revert the entire file and then reapply the changes you'd like to preserve.